# Using absolute phrases to show reason

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, absolute-clauses

I was watching a video and announcer said this:

> "...over the weekend the LA Lakers gave away almost everything to the
>   New Orleans Pelicans, ***the sole reason being*** to bring Anthony
>   Davis to the west coast and give Lebron James all the tools he needed
>   to win a championship."

I think this is the proper way to write it down.

Can I rewrite this sentence as:

> 1a- ...over the weekend the LA Lakers gave away almost everything to
>   the New Orleans Pelicans. ***The sole reason being*** to bring Anthony
>   Davis to the west coast and give Lebron James all the tools he needed
>   to win a championship."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I must admit I cannot fully subscribe to Astralbee's answer.

I do agree with Astralbee that your version is not acceptable formal writing. My reason, however is different. Mine is that your second sentence lacks a verb.

In speech, however, there is no way to distinguish between a comma and a period so that there would be no perceptible difference at all between the first and second versions. This persuades me that breaking the single sentence of the first version into two sentences cannot in and of itself violate the sense of the first version. Your version's second sentence implicitly references the immediately preceding sentence. Such implicit references are acceptable provided that they are sufficiently obvious.

> Over the weekend ... Pelicans. The sole reason was to ...

No one would read that pair of sentences and have any doubt that the reason specified in the second second related to the fact described in the immediately previous sentence. There is no rule that everything to be said on a topic must be crammed into a single sentence.

Nevertheless, I essentially agree with Astralbee about style. Your version does not improve the original; indeed in speech, the two versions are indistinguishable. The version given in Astralbee's answer is more direct, more concise, and so more comprehensible.

Comment: Thank you, could you give your opinion on this version? : "...over the weekend the LA Lakers gave away almost everything to the New Orleans Pelicans, ***with the sole reason being*** to bring Anthony Davis to the west coast and give Lebron James all the tools he needed to win a championship."

Comment: It is grammatical and idiomatic. As a matter of style, I find it a bit verbose. However, sports reporters need to be verbose to fill up column inches with the trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Your re-write doesn't make sense because you have broken it into two sentences.

The original is a statement of what happened, followed by the reason *why*. The phrase "the sole reason being" only serves to qualify that there was only *one* reason why it happened. You could remove those 4 words and it would still make sense:

> Over the weekend the LA Lakers gave away almost everything to the New Orleans Pelicans to bring Anthony Davis to the west coast and give Lebron James all the tools he needed to win a championship.

By breaking it into two sentences you have separated what happened from the reason why and it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I have subtle objections to your answer, not sufficient for me to downvote, but sufficient to generate a somewhat contradictory answer of my own. My objections are too lengthy to fir into a comment. I think, however, we agree on the key point, namely that the OP's version is not an improvement on the original. We differ only on why it is not an improvement.